# Properties of Battacharyya distance vs Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: distributions, probability, kullback-leibler

What properties do these measures have and how can I determine which one is better for a given purpose? What are extreme cases where they differ a lot?

Comment: What is this "given purpose"?

Comment: @mbq: This here, for example: http://www.lscp.net/persons/peperkamp/Peperkamp_Le_Calvez_Nadal_Dupoux_%282006%29_The_acquisition_of_allophonic_rules.pdf (i.e. probability distributions for speech sounds in context of other adjacent sounds) ... but my question aims for a general answer of what I have to take into account when I rate each measure's applicability for any use case.

Answer (score 1):

First properties are explained competently [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback-Leibler_divergence)  and
[there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance).

Which one is better suited to a given purpose will depend on said given purpose so you might think about rephrasing this part of your question.

Comment: @Didier, I feel rephrasing this part of the question will be the hardes part of the job, maybe the question is asking for pairs of (purposes,best distance). But you are right, maybe @Felix could tell us more about why he is asking his question.

Comment: Actually, the first and foremost reason was to get some reputation to be able to answer a question on meta: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/707/could-r-tag-be-displayed-as-a-capital-r . Also, I don't understand much of the wikipedia pages and I have of course read them first. I'm extremely lousy in statistics and maths.

Comment: Dumbfounded by this comment. This is priceless and should be kept for posterity: "Actually, the first and foremost reason [for me to ask this  question] was to get some reputation to be able to answer a question on meta".--Felix Dombek, January 31st, 2011.

Comment: Good that only five are needed ... I don't understand why they don't use the total rep on all SE sites for some actions =)

Comment: I understand that if more points were needed, you would have asked several other fake questions. Is this what you mean?

Comment: This is not a fake question. I do indeed not understand what the different formulas have as implications, and from my comment for the question, it should be evident that I encountered them in real life. If more points were needed, I would either have just dropped it, or possibly just told someone who answered on a previous question of mine what I wanted to answer on meta and asked him to do it for me. Also, I intended to get the points only from accepting an answer (I already had 3 previously) and not from upvotes, but I guess my question isn't bad after all with 3 upvotes so far.

Comment: Also, you must admit that my answer on meta is pretty useful.

Comment: Felix: I simply read what you wrote, nothing else. Now if you'll excuse me, I will take my leave from here.